# Using hook_form_alter() and hook_cron() together

Tags: 7, cron, forms

I am interested in adding a function to the cron queue after I submit a form. I am confused how to call the cron after the form submits.

I am using hook_form_alter for catching the submit:

```
function rating_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id)  {
        case 'comment_node_form':
            $form['#submit'][] = 'add_rating_queue_function';
            break;
     }  
}

function add_rating_queue_function($form, &$form_state) {
    ....
}
```

my hook_cron_queue_info:

```
function add_rating_cron_queue_info(){
  $queues['update_rating'] = array(
    'worker callback' => 'add_rating_queue_function',
    'time' => 120,
  );
  return $queues;
}
```

I am a little confused on how to call `hook_cron` or `hook_cron_queue_info` to add my `add_rating_queue_function` to the cron.

Can I just call `$form['#submit'][] = 'add_rating_cron_queue_info';` inside my `hook_form_alter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't invoke `hook_cron_queue_info()`; you add an item to your cron queue, which is nothing else that a normal [Drupal queue](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7) that is exposed to Drupal cron through [hook_cron_queue_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron_queue_info/7).

What you should do in your `add_rating_queue_function()` is using code similar to the following one.

```
$queue = DrupalQueue::get('update_rating');
// Add a new item to the queue.
$queue->createItem($data);
```

`$data` is the data that is passed to the worker callback you define for the update_rating queue in `add_rating_cron_queue_info()`.

As for running the Drupal cron tasks, you can simply call [drupal_run_cron()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/7). This is what [system_run_cron_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/system_run_cron_submit/7) does.

```
function system_run_cron_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Run cron manually from Cron form.
  if (drupal_cron_run()) {
    drupal_set_message(t('Cron run successfully.'));
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('Cron run failed.'), 'error');
  }

  drupal_goto('admin/config/system/cron');
}
```

`system_run_cron_submit()` is the submission callback for the "Run cron" button you find at admin/config/system/cron.

In your case, you simply need to call `drupal_run_cron()` without checking the error code.

As [Jeremy French](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/182/jeremy-french) [said](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/55095/using-hook-form-alter-and-hook-cron-together/55099#comment58194_55099), `drupal_run_cron()` should not be called too often, and in this way. In admin/config/system/cron, the function call is triggered by the user, but a module should not be calling `drupal_run_cron()`, especially because Drupal 7 includes the code from [Poormanscron](http://drupal.org/project/poormanscron). This mean that cron tasks could be already executed during page requests; adding a further call to `drupal_run_cron()` could make the site slower. A better code could be the following one.

```
if (lock_acquire('cron', 2.0)) {
  $last_cron_execution = variable_get('cron_last', 0);
  lock_release('cron');

  // Check cron tasks were not already executed, or they were not executed few minutes ago.
  // Set $execute if they were executed far enough.

  if ($execute) {
    drupal_run_cron();
  }
}
```

Comment: Alright I think I understand what I need to do now. This clears up my confusion. Thank you.

Comment: May be worth warning that you don't want to be putting 'drupal_cron_run()' in code that end users use. Potentially running cron can impact end user performance.

Comment: @JeremyFrench That is true. I was suggesting the quicker way, but I didn't mean it should be excessively used.